# Infer generic type between 2 props in React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-inference

I believe this is possible but I'm not too good with advanced typing in TS (yet) so:

I want to have a React component accept an array of any object shape in one prop, and then emit that same type in a different (event function) prop.

```
interface Props {
  data: AnyGenericRow[];
  onRow: (row: AnyGenericRow) => void;
}
```

How should I type `AnyGenericRow` to achieve what I want? I suppose I need to infer the type from `data` in some way and then apply that inferred type to the `onRow` signature.

Example usage:

```
const rows: Array<{ foo: 'bar' }> = [];

/* ... */

<Component data={rows} onRow={row => { 
  /* can `row` be detected as a type of { foo: 'bar' } ? */ }
} />
```

Perhaps this is super simple but I find it a bit tricky to know exactly what terms to search for to find this.

Bonus question: Can the inferred generic row extend an interface in the component? Perhaps all it takes is to `&` it...?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you have:

```js
import React from 'react'

interface Props<T> {
    data: T[];
    onRow: (row: T) => void;
}

const rows: Array<{ foo: 'bar' }> = [];

function Component<T>(props: Props<T>) {
    return null
}

<Component data={rows} onRow={row => {
    /* `row` can be detected as a type of { foo: 'bar' } ? */
}} />
```

Please keep in mind that you can also  set generic parameter of `Component` explicitly:

```js
<Component<{ foo: 'bar' }> data={[]} onRow={row => {
    /* `row` can be detected as a type of { foo: 'bar' } ? */
}} />
```

Comment: Thanks, I suspected it was simpler than I would've figured.
+1 for the last tip – I wasn't aware you could specify types directly on components.

Comment: @MagnusBull, this feature was added in TS 2.9, docs -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#generic-type-arguments-in-jsx-elements

Comment: Cool, this really works. Is it possible to write it with ```const Component: React.FC<Props<T>> = ???```

Comment: No, because you dont know T up front