# Infer type from parent props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'd like to know if it's somehow possible, in TypeScript, to infer a type based on the prop of the parent.
Let me explain better with an example: suppose I have `<Parent>` and `<Child>` components, and an interface `IMyComplexObject`.

```
interface IMyComplexObject {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
}

const MyApp = (props) => {
    const [obj, setObj] = React.useState<IMyComplexObject>({name: 'Foo', surname: 'Bar'});

    return (
        <Parent context={obj}>
            <Child value={'name'} />
        </Parent>
    );
}
```

So, what I'm asking is: when I write `<Child value={'name'} />`, is it possible to infer the accepted values for that `value` prop to be `'name' | 'surname'`, which are the keys of `obj`?

I know that, if I had only one component, things would be easy. Suppose this:

```
interface IChildProps<T> {
    ctx: T;
    value: keyof T;
}

- - -

return <Child ctx={obj} value={'name'} />
```

Then, the the intellisense would telling me which are the accepted values:

[image]

But, things get trickier when it's the `<Parent>` component that defines the context, and not the component itself.

EDIT:
To answer @captain-yossarian proposal, the issue with generic type on `<Child>` is that I would end up with a code like:

```
<Parent context={obj}>
    <Child<IMyComplexObject> value={...} />
    <Child<IMyComplexObject> value={...} />
    <Child<IMyComplexObject> value={...} />
    ...
</Parent>
```

Way too many generics (one for each child). More important, there's NO actual connection between the type of the `obj` passed to `<Parent>` and the generic types passed to the `<Child>`s component.
So, for instance, something like this would still be 'legal':

```
interface IObj_1 {
    age: number;
}

interface IObj_2 {
    name: string;
}


const [obj1, setObj1] = React.useState<IObj_1>({age: 7});
const [obj2, setObj2] = React.useState<IObj_2>({name: 'Foo'});

return (
    <Parent context={obj1}>
        <Child<IObj_2> value={'name'} />
    </Parent>
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this approach really makes sense within React, in theory a component should be as self contained as possible, why would you want to do this? (Just wondering if this is an XY problem)

Comment: Ideally, to make a set of components to be used together. I simplified the example, but I suppose that, if I had used the real name for the component, things would be more understandable. Suppose the parent is called `<MyForm>` and the child `<MyTextInput>`: the goal is to define a context in `<MyForm>` and each if its children can exploit that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , it is possible.

You need to provide an explicit generic argument to Child component.

```js
<Child<MyComplexObject> value={"name"} >
```

and Child implementation:

```js
const Child=<T,>(props: {value: keyof T})=>null
```

Or

```js
const Child=<T,>(props: {ctx: T, value: keyof T})=>null
```

**UPDATE**

I think the most simple approach will be to provide `Parent` with extra props: `items` and `callback`

**`items`** - array of keys of `IMyComplexObject`. `items` itself is a primitive value which goes straight to `value` property of `Child`

**`callback`** - `Array.prototype.map` callback.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'


interface IMyComplexObject {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
}

type ParentProps<Context> = {
  context: Context;
  items: Array<keyof Context>;
  callback: (prop: keyof Context) => JSX.Element
}

type ChildProps = { value: string }

const Parent = <Context,>({ items, callback }: ParentProps<Context>) =>
  <>
    {items.map(callback)}
  </>

const Child = ({ value }: ChildProps) => <p>{value}</p>

const MyApp = () => {
  const [context, setContext] = useState<IMyComplexObject>({ name: 'Foo', surname: 'Bar' });

  return (
    <>
      <Parent
        context={context}
        items={['name']}
        callback={
          (prop) => <Child value={prop} />
        }
      />

      <Parent
        context={context}
        items={['hello']} /** expected error */
        callback={
          (prop) => <Child value={prop} />
        }
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC%20cAZlBCHAORSoYsBQPwAdpSh10VAJIBZAJ4BhJmAA2SAB4B5AEYArJBlxc4cPihBIAXHEIwo-AOYBuPefxRDxsxat87XajxiSwVAAKKOwCgYxghAA8sgLKMAB8cAC8uvpoEHFKMGaxlNn2%20sCUIIRmAIJQUCiSUQDWSJIQdHB58QmFcGgo8vJq6HVmABRgEWYNTS1t2QCUKUkAUiQAGgB0AKKKxgLevv5U0gAWwPIAJuEQkSm4cABuPfim5pY2NDwZfBZwwaHwqTGZfJYBJDPDFJClbDdXr9NB1GhmH5IMIRaLTRJzZIJBxRbH6fQ4cGlVYgFBgIbQvoDGY%20fRRAD02K4Hy%20RxOp2uoLuDyo1FyxzOF0imKSUTACRw93kj2oDPF70yXyk5TAYE5IrSXUV8AA2h8gdhiDB0QBda5EUjkShRCQyOSKVSabSJLkuJ4sABiEAgLENTjdZhYACEQiwaDN7A52DB-XAhg46Xj8XSkTtk8n9fFkjhM9laemiiVCNmdSw3SwTfmC5TYXVswmC3HRpcNTEBRypY9s82wLRGQ3k1X8f2B3AoqmYKP0oCszmZ3mp3AicWcKXDkhej7K3B6QAqXdwZQBDBIDlIKrQOC7%20mLmsDeuN-EjCKttlnbnSpDdiJ9pMFof6P2yYMkmEbeEAA)

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of this possible solution. The problem with this is that the type is not inferred by the `<Parent>`, but from the `<Child>` itself. Therefore, I would be flooded with generics. See the edit in the question for better explanation (need multiline code).

Comment: Ok. Understand. You need to do asmall refactor. Parent component should render children as afunction. It will create aconnection between Parent props and Children props. Please see my article https://catchts.com/currying-components . I is not strictly related but might give you an idea. I will provide you with an example later since I am out of keyboard

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean :) Having `<Parent>` return with something like `props.children(props.context)`, and then, where I render the `<Parent>` use something like `<Parent>{ctx => <Child name={ /* Here the type of ctx is inferred */} /></Parent>`.  
This would be certainly a better solution. The best if the direct infer cannot be made.

Comment: Yes, smth like that.

Comment: Might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67869151/infer-generic-type-between-2-props-in-react-typescript/67869368#67869368

Comment: How might this work when the component has multiple props? e.g. `<Child<MyComplexObject> value="name" another="['this', 'is', 'an', 'array']" />`. Do I need to specify each prop in the `Child` with `keyof T` (and will that enable TS to know which key to apply)?

Comment: @fredrivett please provide an example and comment where you expect an error

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine thanks for the swift reply, I've made a separate question to provide more specifics: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73374904/827129