# Infer types from parent props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there a way for my child component to know about the parent component's prop types?

**I don't want to hardcode them into the child, as the child will be used by multiple parents with slightly different props.**

A simplified example:

```js
// Parent.tsx

import React, {ReactElement} from "react";

interface Row {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  tags: string[];
}

const Parent = (): ReactElement => {
  const rows: Row[] = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Foo",
      tags: ["new"],
    },
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Bar",
      tags: ["new", "sale"],
    },
  ];

  const formatRow = (row: Row): ReactElement => (
    <tr key={row.id}>
      <td>{row.id}</td>
      <td>{row.name}</td>
      <td>{row.tags.map(tag => <strong>{tag}</strong>)}</td>
    </tr>
  );

  return <Child formatRow={formatRow} rows={rows} />;
};

export default Parent;
```

```js
// Child.tsx

import React, {ReactElement} from "react";

const Child = ({formatRow, rows}): ReactElement => {
  const columnCount = Object.keys(rows[0]).length;

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map(row => formatRow(row))}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colSpan={columnCount}>Footer</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

There could then also be another parent, `Parent2` with this shape for it's own implementation of `Row`:

```js
// Parent2.tsx

interface Row {
  id: string;
  count: number;
}

const Parent2 = (): ReactElement => {
  // similar code to `Parent` here
};

export default Parent2;
```

I'm not sure how to let the `Child` component know that `formatRow` expects a `Row` and returns a `ReactElement`, and that rows is an array of `Row` objects?

I think Generics might be the answer, but I have extremely limited knowledge on that, so any help whether Generics or otherwise is appreciated.

Comment: You may be looking for a generic

Comment: I think you're right @mousetail, but I'm very new to generics and not sure how to implement one that in this instance

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/NleJRm) works for you

Comment: Thanks @captain-yossarianfromUkraine, naturally my real world code is quite a bit more complex but that seems to do the job, happy to mark that as correct if you pop it up as an answer with a brief explanation. Does it require `rows: R[]` to be before `formatRow: (row: R) => ReactElement` so that `R` in `formatRow` knows it's whatever rows was passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if you want to be `argument agnostic` you should use generics:

```js
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";

interface Row {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  tags: string[];
}

const Child = <R,>({ formatRow, rows }: { rows: R[], formatRow: (row: R) => ReactElement }): ReactElement => {
  const columnCount = Object.keys(rows[0]).length;

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map(row => formatRow(row))}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colSpan={columnCount}>Footer</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  );
};

const Parent = (): ReactElement => {
  const rows: Row[] = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Foo",
      tags: ["new"],
    },
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Bar",
      tags: ["new", "sale"],
    },
  ];

  const formatRow = (row: Row): ReactElement => (
    <tr key={row.id}>
      <td>{row.id}</td>
      <td>{row.name}</td>
      <td>{row.tags.map(tag => <strong>{tag}</strong>)}</td>
    </tr>
  );

  return <Child formatRow={formatRow} rows={rows} />;
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NleJRm)

Here you have simplified version:

```js
interface ChildProps<R> {
  rows: R[],
  formatRow: (row: R) => ReactElement
}

const Child = <R,>({ formatRow, rows }: ChildProps<R>): ReactElement => {
  const columnCount = Object.keys(rows[0]).length;

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map(row => formatRow(row))}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colSpan={columnCount}>Footer</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  );
};
```

So, `R` is infered type of `rows` property. This is how inference works. YOu provide any value to `rows` and `R` will represent type of the value. Then, you  can use `R` for other proeprties.

If you are interested in type inferece on function arguments you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Comment: this looks great, thanks @captain-yossarianfromUkraine, I'll try implementing that into my (more complex) example and hopefully can find my way through, cheers!