# React & TypeScript : props overloading (input string or string[], onChange, same as input)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there a way to define in TypeScript a React Component that allows for the same props to diferent types (but one at a time) and then returns a new value using props callback, of the same type?

Edit: just adapted my sample code with @skyboyer answer.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

type IMyComponentProps<T> = {
    value: T
    onChange: (value: T) => void
}

function MyComponent<T>({
    value,
    onChange
}: IMyComponentProps<string | number>) {
    const onClickHandler = () => {
        if (typeof value === 'number') onChange(value + 1)
        else {
            onChange(value + 'A')
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>{value}</div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Modify</button>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

function Parent() {
    const [x, setX] = useState<string>('A')
    const [y, setY] = useState<number>(1)

    return (
        <div>
            <MyComponent value={x} onChange={setX} />
            <MyComponent value={y} onChange={setY} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

Comment: you need to infer type as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67869151/infer-generic-type-between-2-props-in-react-typescript

Comment: Note that it should be `onChange={setX}`, not `setX()`.

Comment: @skyboyer Already try the T, worked fine till I want to use the useState setter.